# EndExecute in an AsyncCodeActivity Worfklow does not get invoked if there are too many activities

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I am using Workflow to run parallel AsyncCodeActivities using ParallelForEach. While I do so, if there are huge number of activities (say 1000 async activities) then I am getting System.OutOfMemory exception while I run the code.

When I researched more about this by debugging my code, I found out that my "EndExecute" method is not getting invoked for a series of async code activities, even if it has completed its process. Due to this the memory is getting stacked constantly without being released and finally System.OutOfMemory exception is raised. 
I tried to reduce the number of threads to 8 (the number of processors in my machine) but even then I am receiving the exception.

Kindly help me out and I am stuck with this issue for more than a week. I could not find out the solution from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET framework 4.0, I think by limiting max thread pool size by calling SetMaxThreads() to a lower number, will help.
You can get default max thread size by calling GetMaxThread().

Currently OutOfMemory exception is thrown because runtime will keep allocating threadpool thread until memory is available.

You might have to adjust this number depending on memory required for each activity.